# Angular 2 2 way data binding on 2 inputs not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Hello i have this code:

```
<input type="radio" value="{{commencementDate.value}}" id="bankCommencementDateSelect" formControlName="bankCommencementDate">

<input #commencementDate id="bankCommencementDateInput" formControlName="bankCommencementDateInput" type="date" format="DD-MM-YYYY" min="{{ today | date: 'y-MM-dd' }}"/>
```

The value of the date input is being put into the radio input however when i save the form the value is not saving and is causing a error on the required validation on the radio input.

What i want to happen is whatever value is in the date input is set to the value of the radio button so when its saved it works but i ave tryed a few other ways and nothing seems to be working.

Any help would be amazing thanks!

Comment: try using `[value]` instead of just `value`

Comment: I tryed this get the same problem where the data is patched in on change fine but whont save it things its a blank string imgur.com/a/qfI9U

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `formControlName`, the correct way to get the value is like this :

```
<input type="radio" [value]="myForm.get('bankCommencementDateInput').value" id="bankCommencementDateSelect" formControlName="bankCommencementDate">
```

Comment: This is doing the same thing the data is patched in on change fine but whont save it things its a blank string https://imgur.com/a/qfI9U

Answer (score 0):

The best way to set value in Angular reactive from is from a class component using setValue or patchValue.

You can write a function which set value(using patchValue) from a class component on keyup event.